# Testing a Recoil selector with async Query

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, recoiljs

I am using Recoil for state management and have problem testing my selector.
It seems mocking a function inside a selector is not possible.
My code is similar to the code below:

```
const currentUserNameQuery = selector({
  key: 'CurrentUserName',
  get: async ({get}) => {
    const response = await myDBQuery({
      userID: get(currentUserIDState),
    });
    return response.name;
  },
});

function CurrentUserInfo() {
  const userName = useRecoilValue(currentUserNameQuery);
  return <div>{userName}</div>;
}
```

Now, I want to mock the return value of myDBQuery but it seems I cannot do that when using selector. I was wondering if there is any way to mock returned result of a function inside selector.

Comment: Why do you want to test this selector? What would this test achieve? The selector returns a db response based on an id. If you mock the response you are not testing the dependency of the id and you are not testing the query function. So you are basically testing that the selector works, which means that you are just testing if recoil works.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß, I have two reasons to test it. The first one is the test coverage force me to test it. Without testing it I cannot pass 100% coverage. The second reason, as you can see the get in the selector is a function. By testing output of this function I want to ensure nobody in future breaks the result by adding something inside the get function.

Comment: 100% refers to quantity, not quality. Reaching a 100% test coverage does say nothing about the quality of tests and should never be considered a statement of quality. And tbh, this here is the perfect example.
If you mock the result anyway, you are not ensuring that nobody adds something inside the get function. You can never ensure that.
What you are doing here is testing implementation, but you should test behavior. So what you should test is what gets displayed if the selector returns something else. So you should test your hook or component that uses the result of this selector.

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the logic from get into a separate file? After that, you can mock this function.